# Parsing XML using BeautifulSoup or minidom

Tags: python, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, minidom

I have XML something like this

```
#filename sample.xml
<tag>
<tag1>
<tag2 property="something"/>
<tag2 property="something1"/>
<tag2 property="something2">value</tag2>
<tag2 property="something3">
<tag3>
<tag4 data="data1"/>
<tag4 data="data2"/>
</tag3>
</tag2>
</tag1>
</tag>
```

I want to extract `'data1'` and `'data2'`. I'm trying something like this:

```
f=open('sample.xml')
fdata=f.read()
xmldata=BeautifulSoup(fadata)
print (xmldata.tag.tag1.tag2.tag3.tag4["data"])
```

But it's throwing an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag4'
```

Comment: BeautifulStoneSoup belongs to the **obsolete** BeautifulSoup 3; you ought to be using BeautifulSoup4 / `bs4`. And BS3 **cannot** parse XML correctly, whereas BS4 can.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala using bs4. Also how can same be achieved using xml.dom.minidom?

Answer (score 3):

The `print` function is failing due to the multiple `tag2`s. A solution would be to retrieve all the tags by using `.findAll('tag2')`.

Here is a working example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f=open('sample.xml')
fdata=f.read()
xmldata=BeautifulSoup(fdata)

alltags2 = xmldata.tag.tag1.findAll('tag2')

for tag2 in alltags2:
    alltags3 = tag2.findAll('tag3')
    for tag3 in alltags3:
        alltags4 = tag3.findAll('tag4')
        for tag4 in alltags4:
            print "The data I got was :\"%s\"" % (tag4["data"])
```

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is using `select()` method passing CSS selector statement as parameter. For example, if you really want to strictly select `<tag4>` having such ancestor hierarchy :

```
.....
xmldata=BeautifulSoup(fadata)
for tag4 in xmldata.select("tag > tag1 > tag2 > tag3 > tag4"):
    print tag4["data"]
```

Above will print the following :

```
data1
data2
```

Or if you only need all `<tag4>` elements wherever they are located in the XML, you can simply use `xmldata.select("tag4")` .

Comment: if i want to get parent node of tag 4 then what should be done? i tried `x=xmldata.select('tag4')
for node in x:
     print (node.parentNode)`

Comment: you can try : `node.parent` instead of `node.parentNode`